# Parametric3D inconsistencies

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

i wanted to plot a surface of the form

```
thickcurvee[t_, th_] = 
 Simplify[curve[t] + eps *RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, curved2[t]}].{Cos[th], Sin[th], 0},
   Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]
```

With curve and curved2 being maps of R to R^3.
if i plot this surface parametricplot3D plots an empty space, however if i copy paste the result of

```
Simplify[curve[t] + eps *RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, curved2[t]}].{Cos[th], Sin[th], 0},
   Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]
```

directly and define the surface that way parametricplor3D does work.
Does anyone know what causes the difference?

Comment: `thickcurvee[t, th] // Evaluate`

Comment: @cvgmt That does not seem to help.